# Building libcurl using MSYS

Tags: c++, c, libcurl, msys

I have a makefile which builds libcurl static library to use in my project (works perfectly on Linux).

I'm trying to build libcurl on Windows 7 using MSYS but I am struggling.

After solving the 'errors' in the configure script the make command was run and I have received this error:

```
file.c:569: error: too many arguments to function 'Curl_pgrsSetDownloadCounter'
```

at which point the make file terminates.

Comment: Are there any warnings? Did you make changes to the code or did you just do the standard ./configure && make? Which version(s) of curl and MSYS? I compiled curl-7.33 on MSYS recently and had no trouble. I just checked and this function does indeed take two arguments so something else might be going wrong in the build.

Comment: Well there were a bunch of other errors which I didn't include (only the error preceding the termination). I'm using CURL 7.34 and MSYS 1.0. I use ./configure --disabled-shared.

Comment: Hmm. Like you I can build libcurl fine using MSYS but I get those errors when running make recursively from my makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you download MinGW/MSYS from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files

Install MinGW/MSYS and make sure you edit `msys/etc/fstab` to add the following line (with tab between two paths):

```
C:/<path_to_MinGW>      /mingw
```

Then create using notepad or notepad++ an ANSI text file called `build.sh` and paste the following code in it:

(you will need to change the two paths on the top of the file to reflect your folders; also in your case NASM is not needed but I suggest you keep it)

```
#!/bin/sh

# ==================================================================================================================================
#      _____      __                 ______           _                                       __ 
#     / ___/___  / /___  ______     / ____/___ _   __(_)________  ____  ____ ___  ___  ____  / /_
#     \__ \/ _ \/ __/ / / / __ \   / __/ / __ \ | / / / ___/ __ \/ __ \/ __ `__ \/ _ \/ __ \/ __/
#    ___/ /  __/ /_/ /_/ / /_/ /  / /___/ / / / |/ / / /  / /_/ / / / / / / / / /  __/ / / / /_  
#   /____/\___/\__/\__,_/ .___/  /_____/_/ /_/|___/_/_/   \____/_/ /_/_/ /_/ /_/\___/_/ /_/\__/  
#                      /_/                                                                       
# ================================================================================================================================== 

# make sure you edit msys/etc/fstab
# add: C:/<path_to_MinGW>       /mingw

LIBRARY_SOURCES="/d/MyLibs"
NASM="/d/mobileFX/Projects/Software/Coconut/IDE/Studio/etc/3rd_party/nasm/nasm.exe"

cd $LIBRARY_SOURCES

# ==================================================================================================================================
#      __  ____  _ __    
#     / / / / /_(_) /____
#    / / / / __/ / / ___/
#   / /_/ / /_/ / (__  ) 
#   \____/\__/_/_/____/  
#                        
# ==================================================================================================================================

function move_head 
{
    count=`ls $1 | wc -l`   
    if [ "$count" -eq "1" ]
    then        
        t=`ls $1/* -1 -d`       
        for s in `ls -d -1 $1/**/*`
        do          
            mv $s $1
        done
        rm -rf $t
    fi
}

# ==================================================================================================================================
#      __  __          __      __          __  ____       _______       __
#     / / / /___  ____/ /___ _/ /____     /  |/  (_)___  / ____/ |     / /
#    / / / / __ \/ __  / __ `/ __/ _ \   / /|_/ / / __ \/ / __ | | /| / / 
#   / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ / /_/  __/  / /  / / / / / / /_/ / | |/ |/ /  
#   \____/ .___/\__,_/\__,_/\__/\___/  /_/  /_/_/_/ /_/\____/  |__/|__/   
#       /_/                                                               
# ==================================================================================================================================

function update_mingw
{
    mingw-get install msys-wget-bin
    mingw-get install libtool
    mingw-get install unzip

    # Download package config and copy executable to mingw/bin
    wget -c http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/pkg-config_0.23-3_win32.zip
    7z x ./pkg-config_0.23-3_win32.zip -o./pkg-config -y >& /dev/null
    rm -f ./pkg-config_0.23-3_win32.zip
    cp ./pkg-config/bin/pkg-config.exe $MINGW/bin/
    rm -rf ./pkg-config

    # Download glib
    wget -c http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/glib/2.28/glib_2.28.1-1_win32.zip
    7z x ./glib_2.28.1-1_win32.zip -o./glib -y >& /dev/null
    rm -f ./glib_2.28.1-1_win32.zip
    cp ./glib/bin/libglib-2.0-0.dll $MINGW/bin/
    rm -rf ./glib

    # Fixes pkg-config
    curl -L -s -o gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32.zip "http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32.zip"
    7z x ./gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32.zip -o./gettext -y >& /dev/null
    rm -f ./gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32.zip
    cp ./gettext/bin/intl.dll $MINGW/bin/
    rm -rf ./gettext

    # NASM  
    rm -rf $NASM >& /dev/null
    curl -L -s -o nasm-2.07-win32.zip "https://sourceforge.net/projects/nasm/files/Win32%20binaries/2.07/nasm-2.07-win32.zip/download"
    7z x ./nasm-2.07-win32.zip -o$NASM -y >& /dev/null
    rm -f nasm-2.07-win32.zip
    t=`ls $NASM/* -1 -d`
    for i in `ls -d -1 $NASM/**/*`; do mv $i $NASM; done
    rm -rf $t

}

# ==================================================================================================================================
#       ____                      __                __   __    _ __                    _          
#      / __ \____ _      ______  / /___  ____ _____/ /  / /   (_) /_  _________ ______(_)__  _____
#     / / / / __ \ | /| / / __ \/ / __ \/ __ `/ __  /  / /   / / __ \/ ___/ __ `/ ___/ / _ \/ ___/
#    / /_/ / /_/ / |/ |/ / / / / / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ /  / /___/ / /_/ / /  / /_/ / /  / /  __(__  ) 
#   /_____/\____/|__/|__/_/ /_/_/\____/\__,_/\__,_/  /_____/_/_.___/_/   \__,_/_/  /_/\___/____/  
#                                                                                                 
# ================================================================================================================================== 

function download_libraries_sources
{   
    # IMPORTANT: Make sure you download files as <library_name>.tar.gz 

    echo "Download common libraries (stable versions 21 Mar 2016), please wait..."

    curl -L -o curl.zip                 "http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.47.1.zip"
    curl -L -o openssl.tar.gz           "https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz"
}

# ==================================================================================================================================
#       ______     __                  __     ___ __                                                                 
#      / ____/  __/ /__________ ______/ /_   / (_) /_  _________ ________  __   _________  __  _______________  _____
#     / __/ | |/_/ __/ ___/ __ `/ ___/ __/  / / / __ \/ ___/ __ `/ ___/ / / /  / ___/ __ \/ / / / ___/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
#    / /____>  </ /_/ /  / /_/ / /__/ /_   / / / /_/ / /  / /_/ / /  / /_/ /  (__  ) /_/ / /_/ / /  / /__/  __(__  ) 
#   /_____/_/|_|\__/_/   \__,_/\___/\__/  /_/_/_.___/_/   \__,_/_/   \__, /  /____/\____/\__,_/_/   \___/\___/____/  
#                                                                   /____/                                           
# ================================================================================================================================== 

function delete_sources
{
    # Delete all library foldes
    echo "Deleting old sources, please wait..."
    for i in `ls -d */`; do
        t=$(basename "$i")
        echo "+ deleting $t, please wait..."
        rm -rf $t >& /dev/null 
    done
}

function extract_library_sources
{   
    # Save sources
    mkdir ./.src >& /dev/null

    # Extract all library sources
    echo "Extracting sources, please wait..."

    for i in `ls *.zip`; do 
        echo + extracting $i...
        7z x $i -o$(basename "$i" .zip) >& /dev/null
        mv $i ./.src
    done

    for i in `ls *.gz *.xz *.bz2`; do 
        n=`( tar -tf "$i" | head -1 | cut -f1 -d"/" ) 2>/dev/null`
        t=$(basename "$i" .tar.gz)      
        t=$(basename "$t" .tar.xz)      
        t=$(basename "$t" .tar.bz2)     
        echo "+ extracting $i to $t ($n) ..."
        tar xf $i >& /dev/null
        mv $n $t
        mv $i ./.src
    done

    # Detect master folders within library root and move them to root
    for i in `ls -d */`; do move_head $i; done
}

# ==================================================================================================================================
#      ______                      _ __        __    _ __                    _          
#     / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  (_) /__     / /   (_) /_  _________ ______(_)__  _____
#    / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ / / _ \   / /   / / __ \/ ___/ __ `/ ___/ / _ \/ ___/
#   / /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / / /  __/  / /___/ / /_/ / /  / /_/ / /  / /  __(__  ) 
#   \____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/_/_/\___/  /_____/_/_.___/_/   \__,_/_/  /_/\___/____/  
#                       /_/                                                             
# ================================================================================================================================== 

function compile_libraries
{
export "INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include"
export "LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib"
export "BINARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin"

export "CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include"
export "CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include"
export "LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib"

export "PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"

# ==================================================================================================================================
# openssl - OK
# OpenSSL is a well known standard library supporting SSL, i.e. the encrypted HTTPS web protocol.
# Depends on: nothing
# Required by: libcurl
# ================================================================================================================================== 

cd $LIBRARY_SOURCES/openssl
./Configure mingw --prefix=/usr/local shared
make depend
make
make install

# ==================================================================================================================================
# libcurl - OK
# libcurl is a well known library supporting URLs (networking, web protocols)
# Depends on: libz, OpenSSL
# Required by: XMLHttp
# ================================================================================================================================== 

cd $LIBRARY_SOURCES/curl
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared=no --with-zlib=/usr/local
make
make install-strip
make distclean
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared=yes --with-zlib=/usr/local
make
make install-strip

}

update_mingw
download_libraries_sources
delete_sources
extract_library_sources
compile_libraries
```

Normally your could use this script to build any C/C++ library using MinGW/MSYS on Windows, such as cairo, glew, jpeg, libjpeg-turbo, libpng, libxml2, sqlite, zlib, freetype, fontconfig, etc.